# Invisible forward and back buttons for image slideshow + slideshow splacement

Tags: javascript, css, responsive, slideshow

I am trying to create forward and back buttons for my slideshow that are invisible and span past the image to the edge of the page (see [[image: Showing how buttons function on homepage]

I was able to get the slideshow to work on its own, but now that I have plugged it in to the rest of my code It is not spaced evenly and the forward and back buttons do not function.There may be some interaction with the navbar js I am not aware of

I currently have the slides set up so you can only go forward but need to be able to go backword as well and be able to expand forward and back buttons as they are in the photo

Here is my code currently

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})

/* Button code */
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var contentbox = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (contentbox.style.display === "block") {
      contentbox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      contentbox.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
/*slide code */

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function pslide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-links {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom-nav {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.bottom-nav li a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.desktop {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.description {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.Paragraphbox {
  max-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slides {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.slides img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .brand-title {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 30px
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .navbar-links ul .bottom-nav {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Paragraphbox {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding-top: 400px;
  }
  .Paragraphbox a {
    color: blue !important;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
  color: blue !important;
}

.slides {
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media (pointer:none),
(pointer:coarse) {
  .brand-title {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .navbar-links ul .bottom-nav {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .Paragraphbox {
    max-width: 400px;
    padding-top: 400px;
  }
  .Paragraphbox a {
    color: blue !important;
  }
  .slides {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="background_styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>The American Southwest Archive Pt.1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand-title"><strong><a href='/'>Justin Guthrie</a></strong></div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Selected Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="/newworldrites">New World Rites</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shadowboxscultpures">Shadow Box Scultptures</a></li>
        <li class="underline"><a href="/americansouthwest">The American Southwest <br>Archive Pt.1</br></a></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/lariverobjects">L.A. River Objects</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Godisalive">God is Alive</a></li>
        <div class="bottom-nav"><strong>
              <li><a href="/about">About / CV</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://shop.justin-guthrie.com/">Shop</a></li>
            </strong>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class='desktop'>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="img4/1 ACWA Cover.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
        <br><strong>The American Southwest Archive Pt.1</strong>
        <br>2023
        <br>Published by B12 Books
        <br><a href="https://shop.justin-guthrie.com/">Store</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="img4/2 ACWA pages.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
      </div>
      <div class="slides">
        <img src="img4/3 ACWA pages.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Insivible? This is a very bad design decision UX-wise

Comment: You have javascript errors because you are referring to elements with the classname of dot, but have none

Answer (score 1):

please don't take my world personally but there is a lot of error in your code per example:

```
.toggle-button {
 position: absolute;
 top: .75rem;
 right: 1rem;
 display: none;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 50px;
 height: 40px;
}
```

This line won't never justify the items cause the display is not flex ...
I can help, but you'll need to make a reproducible code in CodePen.

Comment: great thank you wil improve code

Answer (score 0):

So to make it invisible, I have set `background-color: transparent`.
Full code below:

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})

/* Button code */
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var contentbox = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (contentbox.style.display === "block") {
      contentbox.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      contentbox.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
/*slide code */

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function pslide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  try{dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";}
  catch (e){}
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 25px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar-links {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom-nav {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.bottom-nav li a {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.desktop {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.description {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.Paragraphbox {
  max-width: 700px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.slides {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

.slides img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .brand-title {
font-size: 3.5em;
margin-right: 200px;
margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .navbar {
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
width: 90%;
  }
  .toggle-button {
display: flex;
margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links {
display: none;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 30px
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
font-size: 3em;
  }
  .navbar-links ul .bottom-nav {
font-size: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
display: flex;
  }
  .Paragraphbox {
max-width: 400px;
padding-top: 400px;
  }
  .Paragraphbox a {
color: blue !important;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
  color: blue !important;
}

.slides {
  font-size: 30px;
}
leftBox{float: left;}
#rightBox{float: right;}
#leftBox, #rightBox{
width: 40%;
height: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
flex-direction: row;
}
@media (pointer:none),
(pointer:coarse) {
  .brand-title {
font-size: 3.5em;
margin-right: 200px;
margin-left: 50px;
  }
  .navbar {
flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
width: 90%;
  }
  .toggle-button {
display: flex;
margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links {
display: none;
width: 100%;
background-color: white;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
width: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
font-size: 3em;
  }
  .navbar-links ul .bottom-nav {
font-size: 30px;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
display: flex;
  }
  .Paragraphbox {
max-width: 400px;
padding-top: 400px;
  }
  .Paragraphbox a {
color: blue !important;
  }
  .slides {
font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="background_styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>The American Southwest Archive Pt.1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
<div class="brand-title"><strong><a href='/'>Justin Guthrie</a></strong></div>
<a href="#" class="toggle-button">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</a>
<div class="navbar-links">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Selected Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/newworldrites">New World Rites</a></li>
    <li><a href="/shadowboxscultpures">Shadow Box Scultptures</a></li>
    <li class="underline"><a href="/americansouthwest">The American Southwest <br>Archive Pt.1</br></a></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/lariverobjects">L.A. River Objects</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Godisalive">God is Alive</a></li>
    <div class="bottom-nav"><strong>
          <li><a href="/about">About / CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://shop.justin-guthrie.com/">Shop</a></li>
        </strong>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
  </nav>

  <div class='desktop'>
<span  id="leftBox" onclick="pslide(-1)"></span>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="img4/1 ACWA Cover.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
    <br><strong>The American Southwest Archive Pt.1</strong>
    <br>2023
    <br>Published by B12 Books
    <br><a href="https://shop.justin-guthrie.com/">Store</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="img4/2 ACWA pages.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
  </div>
  <div class="slides">
    <img src="img4/3 ACWA pages.jpg" onclick="pslide(1)">
  </div>
  
</div>
  <span id="rightBox" onclick="pslide(1)"></span>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```